# Код работает, если ввести в javascript-консоль, но не работает из листинга кода

Tags: javascript, консоль

```js
function soundClick() {
  var aud = 'http://chanson.hostingradio.ru:8041/chanson128.mp3?'; // путь к аудиофайлу
  var audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = aud; // Указываем путь к звуку "клика"
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else if (audio.played) {
    audio.pause();
  }
};

$('#goFm').click(soundClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="goFm">Click</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте перенести вызов `$('#goFm').click(soundClick);` в `$(document).ready` таким образом `$(document).ready(function() {$('#goFm').click(soundClick);});`

Comment: где `goFm` и где код?

Comment: У вас при каждом клике создается экземпляр `new Audio();`. Если вы хотите вкл/выкл проигрывание, `var audio` нужно вынести в глобальные переменные (например) и создавать экземпляр лишь один раз, а при последующих кликах только проверять состояние

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У тебя все прекрасно работает, просто объект Audio вывести за функцию, потому, что при каждом клике ты создаешь новый объект Audio а старый остается, а так все прекрасно работает

```js
var aud = 'http://chanson.hostingradio.ru:8041/chanson128.mp3?'; // путь к аудиофайлу
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = aud; // Указываем путь к звуку "клика"
function soundClick() {

  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
  } else if (audio.played) {
    audio.pause();
  }
};

$('#goFm').click(soundClick);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="goFm">Click</div>
```